# How can I deteremine if I'd read something from a socket?

Tags: windows, perl, sockets

The following piece of code is supposed to read a few, undetermined in number, lines from a socket.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;

my $server = shift;
my $port   = shift;

my $sock  = new IO::Socket::INET (
               PeerAddr    => $server,
               PeerPort    => $port,
               Proto       => 'tcp',
               Timeout     =>  1,
               Blocking    =>  0
           ) 
           or die "Could not connect";

while (my $in = <$sock>) {
  print "$in";
}

print "Received last line\n";
```

Unfortunately, the `$in = <$sock>` part is blocking although I have set `Blocking => 0` and the server does not send any more text. Hence, `Received last line` won't be printed.

So, I tried to improve the behavior with `use IO::Select`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use IO::Select;

my $server = shift;
my $port   = shift;

my $sock  = new IO::Socket::INET (
               PeerAddr    => $server,
               PeerPort    => $port,
               Proto       => 'tcp',
               Timeout     =>  1,
               Blocking    =>  1
           ) 
           or die "Could not connect";

my $select = new IO::Select;
$select -> add($sock);

sleep 1;
while ($select -> can_read) {
  my $in = <$sock>;
  print $in;
}
```

This second approach only prints the first sent line, then seems to block for ever.

Since I have seen such examples working, I believe the problem is Windows, on which I am trying to run these scripts.

Is there a way how I can achieve a non blocking read?

Comment: `select` (used by `can_read`) works fine with sockets on Windows. If fact, that's the only type of handles on which it works in Windows

Comment: Might want to add `$| = 1;` if you're going to print partial lines

Comment: might try adding a line feed after your print - it might just be not printing your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `select` (used by `can_read`), it defies the purpose to follow up with blocking IO. You must also avoid buffering IO because the system (i.e. `select`) doesn't know about any data in your library's buffers. This means you can't mix `select` with `read`, `readline` (aka `<>` and `<$fh>`) and `eof`. You must use `sysread`.

```
my %clients;
for my $fh ($select->can_read()) {
   my $client = $clients{$fh} //= {};
   our $buf; local *buf = $client->{buf} //= '';   # alias my $buf = $client->{buf};
   my $rv = sysread($sock, $buf, 64*1024, length($buf));
   if (!defined($rv)) {
      my $error = $!;
      $select->remove($fh);
      delete($clients{$fh});
      # ... Handle error ...
      next;
   }

   if (!$rv) {
      $select->remove($fh);
      delete($clients{$fh});
      # ... Handle EOF ...         # Don't forget to check if there's anything in $buf.
      next;
   }

   ... remove any complete messages from $buf and handle them ...
}
```

If you want to read a line at a time, you'd use

```
while ($buf =~ s/^([^\n]*)\n//) {
   process_msg($client, $1);
}
```