# How does Perl know how many bytes to read in a handle from IO::Select::->can_read?

Tags: perl, ipc

I'm using `IO::Select`'s `can_read` method to select file handles that are ready for reading in a simple perl script.

However, the `<...>` operator on filehandles does not require a length to be passed to it.

Is `IO::Select` reaching inside the filehandle to set the "appropriate length" ... or what exactly is happening?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use IO::Select;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @handles = IO::Select->new(\*STDIN)->can_read(3);

@handles == 1 or die;

my $handle = $handles[0];

print ("I read " . <$handle> . "\n");
```

For instance, the following script prints `"a\n"` immediately and then exits after three seconds.

```
% sh -c 'echo a; sleep 5; echo b' | perl reader.pl
I read a

Exit 141
```

It then exits abnormally for some strange reason ... not sure where the exit status is being set.

EDIT: the apparent abnormal exit appears to be a bug in tcsh.

Comment: Which perl version? On 5.20 it waits for 5 sec and terminates normally.

Comment: perl 5.24 on OS X ... I suspect the exit status is being reported erroneously by tcsh :/

Comment: can_read uses select() https://metacpan.org/source/GBARR/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Select.pm#L99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither IO::Select knows the length nor the `<...>` operator or `readline` function knows it. Instead it will just try to read what is there until the end of the line. If no end of line character is found (i.e. `$/`) it will simply return all available data in case of non-blocking file handle or wait until end of line or end of data in case of a blocking file handle.

In your specific case `echo a; sleep 5; echo b` results in a line `a\n` and 5 seconds later in a line `b\n`. Since your code uses  `<..>` in scalar context it will only read a single line. This means it will stop after the first line end was found and return this line, resulting in `a\n`.

Comment: Also, mixing buffered I/O (`<` `>`, `readline`) and unbuffered I/O (`select`, `can_read`, `sysread`) on the same handle is a very bad idea.

Comment: so then with `select` and the `IO::Select` wrappers over select ... how do I get the length of the content I can read for the filehandles. I think `sysread` requires a length since it's a thin wrapper over `read(2)`.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet:  the length parameter in sysread  specifies how much you __want__ to read at most not how much you __will__ read. If less data are available sysread will return these data (or block if no data are available at all but no end of data too).

Comment: @Gregory Nisbet, If you are reading from multiple handles, your code will look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33206116/589924)